# Background Cover JPG not rendering on mobile devices

Tags: jpeg, css

I've setup two pages with the `background-size:cover;` with one using a `.jpg` and one using a `.png`. Both pages render fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox on the desktop, but for some reason the `.jpg` version does not render on iPhone/iPad in Chrome/Safari.

- [PNG Version](http://dev.florig.org/bgcovertest/png.html)
- [JPG Version](http://dev.florig.org/bgcovertest/jpg.html)

I suspect it might have something to do with the compression of the `.jpg` which I set to the lowest (smallest file size) setting in Photoshop, but I could not find any actual info on this. Any advice is much appreciated!

**EDIT**:

I am already using the browser specific prefixes in my css (e.g. `-webkit-`,`-moz`,`-o-`).

Comment: can you paste the actual code that you are using?

Comment: You can view the source of the two pages I linked for the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size` is a new CSS property and therefore isn't available everywhere yet

although in mobile devices `-webkit-background-size:cover;` should do the trick

Comment: This does not address my question.

Answer (score 0):

For Safari versions <**5.1** the css3 property `background-size` doesn't work. In such cases you need `webkit`.

So you need to use `-webkit-background-size` attribute to specify the **background-size**.

Hence use `-webkit-background-size:cover`.

Reference-**[Safari versions using webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history)**

Comment: If you look at the source code of the pages I linked, you can see that I am using the `-webkit-background-size:cover` on both pages. The only issue is on a mobile device viewing the `jpg` version.